# Live Agent- Pre-Chat

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I am not able to create/find record using the Pre-Chat Api tags...Any help you guys can give will be appreciated. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="prechatFormPanel">
    <form method="post" id="preChatFormSubmit" action="{!endpoint}"> 

        <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:Email" value="{!formEmail.value}"/>

        <input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="Email,Email;" />
        <input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value= "Email, true;" />
        <input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value= "Email, true;" />
        <input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value= "true" />
    </form> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I had issues to, and couldn't get it to actually create something.  I was able to get the query working as documented in the answer to [How to setup pre-chat form in HTML to embed in customer website](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/how-to-setup-pre-chat-form-in-html-to-embed-in-customer-website).  Someone else just had a bounty on a similar question as yours and nobody answered it. Perhaps [this question helps](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21229/live-agent-what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-create-a-case-from-the-pre-chat-form)?

Comment: Yeah the query works fine..I tried the syntax you recommended already and it did not work. The only way it works is by using the Deployment API and not the Pre-Chat Api. Thank you I keep trying and looking for the answer

Answer (score 5):

The syntax you have to find an existing record looks correct.  I assume that you have a button somewhere or something to actually submit the form.

You haven't specified what to create if it isn't found.  You do that with the [map.doCreate method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_prechat_API_doCreate.htm).  The doFind alone does not create a new record.  If it doesn't find anything the console just stays on the Visitor Details page.  I think you'll need to specify a LastName as well since that's required on Contact.  You don't have to search by that though, if you don't want to. The way that the Pre-Chat API works is that it will try to find with the doFind and then if not found will actually create the record with the doCreate. It doesn't just take you to a new record screen with values filled in. It actually creates, so you need required fields. Here's a snippet that should do it:

```
<form method="post" id="prechatForm" action="{!endpoint}"> > 
    <input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:Email" value="{!formEmail.value}"/>
    <input type="text" name="liveagent.prechat:LastName" />

    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="Email,Email;LastName,LastName;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" /> 

    <!-- specify that the created record should have email and last name on it -->   
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact" value="Email,true;LastName,true;" />

    <!-- Save the Contact to the Lookup field on the Live Chat Transcript -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="Contact" />

    <input type="submit" value="Request Chat" />
</form>
```

Also, it could be the endpoint variable is wrong or the value of formEmail.value not what you expect it.  You can double check the Email custom detail that was submitted on the Visitor Details in the console when you accept the chat or the mouseover pop out of the chat before you accpet it on the request panel.

---

You can read more about the Live Agent Pre-Chat API in a [detailed article I just posted](http://peterknolle.com/live-agent-pre-chat-api/). It steps through code for a contrived Pre-Chat form that collects input, searches for a Contact, creates one if not found, creates a Case, links the Contact to the Case, and the Case and Contact to the Live Chat Transcript record.